# SQL Where Column Contains String separated by 11 random characters and then string

Tags: sql, where-clause

I need to select a column based on the following condition:

If a column contains the string `'Alerting'` followed by 11 random characters including blank spaces and then `'Hold'`?

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM INTERACTIONSUMMARY
WHERE CALLEVENTLOG LIKE 'Alerting___________Hold';
```

Comment: What results did the query you tried return, and how were the results wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of your substrings below or place wildcards after the word to do your condition.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Alerting___________Hold', 0, 9) -- Alerting
SELECT SUBSTRING('Alerting___________Hold', 20, 4) -- Hold

SELECT * 
FROM INTERACTIONSUMMARY
WHERE CALLEVENTLOG LIKE ('Alerting%') AND CALLEVENTLOG LIKE ('%Hold')`
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards (%) on the outside and underscores for the 11 places. Please review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) for additional information.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    val VARCHAR(200)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 'Super duper test Alerting12345678912Hold'

SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE val LIKE '%Alerting___________Hold%'
```